# Node JS, chaining variable number of http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using `request js` library to make HTTP requests to my API. My single API call looks like this:

```
var options = {
  method: "post",
  url: 'http//example.com',
  json: true,
  headers: headers,
  body: {key: value}
}
request(options, callback);
```

However, I have array of `options`, which are needed to be called **one after another** and I need to break whole chain if one of them fails.

If last chain finishes, I need to output result to console.

I know that chaining callbacks could be fulfilled via promises, but all examples that I have found uses predefined amount of chained requests.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have to follow a defined sequence? If not why not promise.all?

Comment: why do you need to run each promise sequentially? they can be run in the same time using Promise.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array, you can have an index into that array, and have the callback kick off the next request when the previous one finishes. Roughly:

```
var index = 0;
var options = [/*...array of options objects...*/];
doRequest() {
    request(options[index], function(err, result) {
        // ...handle the result/error here. If there's no error, then:
        if (++index < options.length) {
            // Kick off the next request
            doRequest();
        }
    });
}
```

While the above *can* be Promise-ified, since your `request`method appears not to be, it would just complicate things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is simpler and more understandable. I feel so stupid now :).

Comment: @Mr.D: We all had to learn things the first time, don't beat yourself up!

Answer (score 2):

A recursive function which calls itself in the request callback should work.

```
options = [{...}, {...}];

function doRequests(options){

    request(options.shift(), function(){

        if(error){
            return "handle error";
        }

        if(options.length > 0){
            doRequests(options);
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do would be to use a request library that returned a promise. Assuming you have such a thing then you just chain the promises together.

First create a resolved promise:

```
var promise = new Promise.resolve();
```

The for each new object you want to request:

```
promise = promise.then(() => requestToPromise(options));
```

will chain another request onto the existing promise and will fire off a new request only when the previous one has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise)

and do the following

```
import request = require('request-promise');

var options = [/*...array of options objects...*/];
requests = [];
options.forEach(function(option){
    requests.push(request(option));
}
Promise.all(requests).then(function(reponses){
    //all requests are done.
});
```